# packing unsigned char bytes into an unsigned int in c

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit, pack

I have an assignment in which I have to pack the bytes from 4 unsigned char into an unsigned int.

the code goes as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    //Given this
    unsigned char a = 202; 
    unsigned char b = 254; 
    unsigned char c = 186; 
    unsigned char d = 190; 

    //Did this myself
    unsigned int u = a; 
    u <<=8; 
    u |= b; 
    u <<=8; 
    u |= c
    u <<=8; 
    U |= d; 
}
```

I know that:

```
u <<=8;
```

Shifts the bits in u to the left 8. But I am confused as to what the lines like `u |= b;`do?

Simply, I am trying to better understand what the code I came up works into packing the bytes from 4 unsigned char into an unsigned int. I came up with this solution in a brute type of way. I was just trying to pack bytes in different ways, and this way worked. But I am not really sure why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` which is `202` in binary would be `11001010`

`b` which is `254` in binary would be `11111110`

`c` which is `186` in binary would be `10111010`

`d` which is `190` in binary would be `10111110`

```
unsigned int u = a;
u <<= 8;    // now u would be 11001010 00000000
u |= b;     // now u would be 11001010 11111110
u <<= 8;    // now u would be 11001010 11111110 00000000
u |= c;     // now u would be 11001010 11111110 10111010
u <<= 8;    // now u would be 11001010 11111110 10111010 00000000
u |= d;     // now u would be 11001010 11111110 10111010 10111110
            // This is how        a        b        c        d    
            // are packed into one integer u.
```